# Getting cors error in .net framework in release release

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, .net-framework-version

Every thing worked fine in debug mode but i am facing cors error in release mode

i am using oauth for authentication for now i am allowing all origins but when i try to get token i am getting the cors error

```
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
```

and also provided in webapiconfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*"));
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: idk much about c, but if you control the server, then add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the request coming in.

Comment: Sorry ur answer isn't helping me